# How to implement Interstitial ads in android app without button click?

Tags: android

I have develop android app. How to add Interstitial ads into my android app without button click?

Comment: check this out https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //instantiating PublisherInterstitialAd
    mPublisherInterstitialAd = new PublisherInterstitialAd(this);
    //setting ad unit ID.
    mPublisherInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId("/6499/example/interstitial");
    //loading the ad
    mPublisherInterstitialAd.loadAd(new PublisherAdRequest.Builder().build());
    //showing the ad
    if (mPublisherInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
        mPublisherInterstitialAd.show();
    } else {
        Log.d("TAG", "The interstitial wasn't loaded yet.");
    }


    mPublisherInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAdLoaded() {
            // Code to be executed when an ad finishes loading.
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {
            // Code to be executed when an ad request fails.
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdOpened() {
            // Code to be executed when the ad is displayed.
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdLeftApplication() {
            // Code to be executed when the user has left the app.
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdClosed() {
            // Code to be executed when when the interstitial ad is closed.
            // Load the next interstitial.
            mPublisherInterstitialAd.loadAd(new PublisherAdRequest.Builder().build());
        }
    });
}



dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:12.0.0'
}
```